# Методы get и set

Tags: ооп, php

Не могу найти применение методам **get и** set. Если они устанавливают значение нового свойства объекта, то что мне мешает обойтись и без них, написав :

```
class C1 {

}
$a = new C1();
$a->new_prop = 100500;
echo $a->new_prop;
```

А что конкретно дают эти методы? В документации красивая теория, но я не пойму их основное практическое предназначение! У меня все классы работают без них. Возможно, мой код станет более лаконичным, если я осмыслю их суть. Пожалуйста, если можно пример кода, где без **этих методов** просто не обойтись.

**UPDATE** До этого я работал с процедурным стилем программирования, поэтому некоторые фишки типа get и set для меня - загадка.

Comment: Надо бы уточнить о чём именно речь. Если имеются в виду методы для получения и установки значений, так они могут работать с закрытыми членами класса, например. К которым напрямую не обратиться. Если же имеются в виду специфичные для PHP методы `__get()` и `__set()`, то это совсем другая история.

Comment: @klopp, имеются в виду как раз специфичные для PHP

Comment: А, форматирование подчёркивания сожрало. Тут, например: [методы-перехватчики](http://biznesguide.ru/coding/144.html).

Comment: @klopp, спасибо за ссылку. Не буду открывать новую тему, но иногда объект создается БЕЗ скобок - $obj = new Class_name. В чем отличие от new Class_name()? В жабаскрипте разница есть, а в пхп?

Comment: @Deus, нет никакой разницы. Как писать зависит от принятого соглашения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот вопрос касается ООП в целом, а не только PHP.
Использование геттеров и сеттеров дает вам такие плюсы как:

1. Сокрытие реализации
2. Возможность выполнения дополнительных действий при установке/чтении

Первый пункт позволяет вам в будущем изменить способ хранения данных внутри класса. Например, хранили вы всегда пользовательский email как строку, а потом захотели хранить его как пары: логин/домен.
Работая с геттером и сеттером, ничего менять вне класса не придется, а работая напрямую придется перебрать весь код, обращающийся к полю email.

Второй, как следствие первого - позволяет делать что-угодно, когда выполняется установка или чтение значения. Например, выполнять валидацию поля или увеличение каких-то счётчиков.

Что касается `__get()` и `__set()`, то они полезны, когда вы не знаете, что там у вас спросят. Например, если вы работаете с каким-то API. Прямо в этих методах вы можете сформировать обращение к тому же API совершенно для пользователя вашего модуля.

Comment: Добавил пару строк о ``__get()`` и ``__set()``.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, ок. Теперь только практика. А насчет скобок в инициализации объекта - весьма удивлен. В яваскрипте объект со скобками, и без  - это совершенно разные сущности

Comment: @Deus, эти языки совершенно разные. К счастью :)